# Build a chat application using NestJs

Tags: websocket, postman, nestjs

I want to build a chat application using NestJs currently I am using webs socket, there are 3 user which are connected to my gateway and all 3 of them are getting data.
I want to establish a one to one connection or personal chat where only 2 user can connect and then send data to each other without other user getting data.

I created a webSocketGateway and in that I created a function handeConnection which send all messages stored in database, and a sendMessage function which emit a single message to all user.

Comment: Make the WebSocket event name dynamically (Using user id with the event name like that)

Comment: How will I know to which user I am sending message.

Comment: For this, You have to make your WebSocket URL privately (You need to handle the private route with JWT authentication here the token is created by the user ID, email, and so on). 
So whenever the user connects to that web socket, you have to decode the JWT token and get the current user ID from that token (This is how we can identify who belongs to that message).

Comment: So i will get receiver user email ,id and other things from fronted and then will create a token and send it to back end in headers and using to() function i will send it to that user.

Comment: While creating the user we will get the user email from the front end, The ID should be unique so that should be created by the backend, While that user login we will create a JWT token using the user ID and mail and send it to frontend, and after the login, all other API call should come with the header Authorization with the value JWT token. so if we get the token from the front end, we can get the current user ID from that token.